# Vim | Show window with output after issuing external command

Tags: vim

After I issue external command in Vim, say, ls, with `:!ls` it produces buffer with output. This buffer can be seen till Enter of Esc buttons aren't pressed.

How can one display this window again? What is the ex's command or key sequence to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
:!
```

This should show the window again.

For the binding you can create a mapping, for example:

```
map <leader>s :!<cr>
```

Or any combination you like.

By default `<leader>` corresponds to `\` but I changed to a `,`, so when I press `,` + `s` the window show up again.

Comment: It's strange, it does in my vim (7.4).

Comment: @Зелёный Oh, my solution only works in the terminal, not in gvim :(

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
:new | r ! <command>
```

e.g.

```
:new | r ! ls
```

This puts the output of your command into a new regular buffer.